# Can't see my desktop in KDE Neon

Tags: tty, kde-plasma-5, kde-neon

I did run some commands that caused corrupting my KDE Neon. It doesn't shows my desktop and it starts in the command. Can I do something so I can get back my desktop? or should I install the new one?

I already tried

```
sudo apt-get remove plasma-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and it didn't work

and I cannot install anything either because of the error

```
unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

and the main problem was this.

So I did everything but they didn't work. I tried to solve the problem by these

[Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

[Fix: Unable to Correct Problems ‘You have Held Broken Packages’](https://appuals.com/fix-unable-correct-problems-held-broken-packages/)

Still I have the problem. What should I do?!

Answer (score -1):

If you're unable to restore your KDE Neon desktop after running commands that caused corruption, and you're encountering errors like "unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages," you might need to consider reinstalling the operating system as a last resort. However, before doing so, you could try accessing recovery options or using a live USB to troubleshoot and repair the system. If these methods fail, reinstalling might be the most effective solution.